# How to remove duplicate entries in a dataframe in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

The following is the table I have.

```
|    Path    | Name | Value 1 | Value 2 |  E-mail  |
|:----------:|:----:|:-------:|:-------:|:--------:|
| /project/a | a    |  10000  |  8555   | xy@xy.com|
| /project/b | b    |  4000   |  7549   | ab@ab.com|
| /project/c | c    |  4571   |  4478   | vb@vb.com|
| /project/a | a    | -1.0    |  0.0    | xy@xy.com|
```

Schema:

Path - string 

Name - string 

Value 1 - float 

Value 2 - float 

E-mail - string

Now I want to filter out the last repeating name row (a is repeating again) completely while sending the report to the concerned person in the e-mail column.

I have tried using the condition statements (if statement) but it is not working. What should I do?

```
if (project["Name"] == 'a' and project["Value 1"] == '-1.0'):
    continue
else:
    mail_notification(sender,receiver,subject)
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "it is not working"? Also, how do you use the code you provide on your dataframe? With a UDF? By collecting all the data onto the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicates from a dataframe based on a column (or set of columns) you can use [dropDuplicates](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html). Note that it may not drop the second one, ordering is not deterministic and this should be used when the rest of the fields are either the same or irrelevant.
eg.:

```py
deduplicated = df.dropDuplicates(['Name'])
```

If you want ordering for deduplication preference, you can use window functions ([row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html), [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/window.html)). For example, choosing the row for the highest "Value 1" in the duplicate group:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window().partitionBy('Name').orderBy(f.desc('Value 1'))
deduplicated = df.withColumn('row_number', f.row_number().over(window))\
    .filter(f.col('row_number') == 1)\
    .drop('row_number')
```

If you just want to drop negative values as they are not valid data, the easiest is to filter:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
filtered = df.filter(f.col('Value 1') >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below one -

1. Create dataframe
2. Iterate in for loop -

```
for i in df.collect():
    if ((i["Name"] == 'a') & (i["Value 1"] == -1.0)):
        continue
    else:
        mail_notification(sender,receiver,subject)
```

Comment: I have followed the same procedure but its not working

Comment: Do you have any other ideas